# Why do Eclipse Luna Maven projects give errors for maven-compiler-plugin?

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-luna

When I create a new Maven project in Eclipse Luna it gives this error as soon as the project is created:

> Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (execution: default-compile, phase: compile) pom.xml /intercept  line 1  Maven Project Build Lifecycle Mapping Problem

There is nothing in the project except for the pom.xml, and I can't add a Java class because it thinks it is not a Java project.  If I run `mvn clean install` from the command line it builds successfully.  This looks like it is the Eclipse - Maven integration that is broken in Luna.

This doesn't happen with Kepler.  What got broken in Luna?  I am behind a firewall and a proxy server that prevent certain kinds of internet access.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this answer it might be able to help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9142610/1570834

Answer (score 1):

From https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4236 and crediting the user on that site who provided the answer:

Martin Lippert (c) added a comment - 27/Oct/15 7:04 AM

I can reproduce this behavior, but can't find the root cause of it yet. It seems to happen after updating STS, but not updating the m2e components for whatever reason.

The way to solve this is to update the used m2e and m2e-wtp components in STS by installing those updates via "Install New Software" from:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases
http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/mars/
```

After that update, the lifecycle mapping should work fine again.
I am still getting an issue when running this on a JDK6, but that is a different story.